# Tabularray +pmatrix not working in align

Tags: math-mode, tabularray

It seems that the `tabularray` environment `+pmatrix` does not work with `align` environments.
Is there a fix or something I am missing?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a + b 
    \begin{+pmatrix}
        a & a \\
        b & a \\
    \end{+pmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

```
Error:
Argument of \+pmatrix has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.21 \end{align}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a small problem with `tblr` used in math mode which was, in fact, corrected with today's version of `tabularray` (version 2022B).

Either wait for the new version to propagate through the servers, or enclose the `pmatrix` environment in braces:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a + b 
    {
    \begin{+pmatrix}
        a & a \\
        b & a \\
    \end{+pmatrix}
    }
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'm actually eagerly waiting for the new version to reach my TeX Live mirror!

Comment: Thank you for the help!